# How read a json file with mule?

Tags: json, mule, esb

I have this section in my source code:

```
<file:inbound-endpoint connector-ref="fileConnector" path="C:/tmp/input" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/json">
       <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.json"/>
</file:inbound-endpoint>

<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap"/>

<logger level="INFO" message="#[message.payload]"/>
```

everything compile fine! but at execute throws the next exception: **"Message: failed to transform from "json" to "java.util.HashMap" Code: MULE-ERROR-109"**

Can anyone help me about this error?

Comment: What is your JSON payload ?? Do you want to print the payload in log or want to extract element value from it ?

Comment: I'm debugging my flow and the content of payload is a array of byte[]. How i do to convert this array to a json file?

Comment: I'm putting a byte-array-to-object and object-to-json, now i have a string of content of my file like this "param : \r\n{\r\n\t\t\t[\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\"key\":\"1\"]..........}". **How to select a value of "key" in my payload?**

Comment: What is your Json content ? What you want to print in log ..the entire Json or any specific json value ?

Comment: This doesn't look like valid JSON, that's probably why you can't use the `json-to-object-transformer`.

Comment: Can you please include in your description the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: `<file:inbound-endpoint  connector-ref="fileConnector"  path="C:/tmp/input" doc:name="File Input" responseTimeout="10000" encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="application/json">
  <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.json"/>
  </file:inbound-endpoint>  
<byte-array-to-object-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to Object"/>
  
<json:object-to-json-transformer />

<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.Map" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
 
<logger level="INFO" message="#[payload]" doc:name="Logger" />
` This is the entire file definition and this is the stacktrace

Comment: Message               : Failed to transform from "json" to "java.util.Map"
Code                  : MULE_ERROR-109
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Exception stack is:
1. Can not instantiate value of type [map type; class java.util.LinkedHashMap, [simple type, class java.lang.Object] -> [simple type, class java.lang.Object]] from JSON String; no single-String constructor/factory method (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException)
2. Failed to transform from "json" to "java.util.Map"

Comment: Pls provide your json content

Comment: Thanks for the help. The mistake was in the JSON file. I took the liberty to answer the thread myself explaining the case, for it is as a knowledge base for the future. Again thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The flow was as follows:**

> ```
> <file:inbound-endpoint 
>   connector-ref="fileConnector" path="C:/tmp/input" 
>   doc:name="File Input" responseTimeout="10000" 
>   encoding="UTF-8" mimeType="text/plain">
>   <file:filename-wildcard-filter pattern="*.json"/>
> </file:inbound-endpoint>
>
> <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.HashMap"doc:name="JSON to Object"/>`
> ```
>
> The error was in the JSON file. The character
>   encoding was not right and for this reason I was generating errors
>   when trying to transform through `<json: json-to-object-transformer
>   returnClass = "java.util.HashMap" doc: name = "JSON to Object" / >`
>   after making reading the file with `<file: inbound-endpoint>`
>   attribute where I had defined as *encoding = "UTF-8"*

**Solution**

> Change the character encoding of the JSON file to "UTF-8"

**Knowledge Base:**

> If the exception stack is:
>
> Message: Failed to transform from "json" to "java.util.HashMap" Code:
>   MULE_ERROR-109
>
> ---
>
> Exception stack is:
>
> 1. Unexpected character ((code 65279 / 0xFEFF) '?'): Expected to valid value (number, string, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')  at [Source: java.io.InputStreamReader@2fba237; line 1, column 2 (org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException) org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser: 1433 (null)
> 2. Failed to transform from "json" to "java.util.HashMap (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerException) org.mule.module.json.transformers.JsonToObject: 132
>      (http://www.mulesoft.org/docs/site/current3/apidocs/org/mule/api/transformer/TransformerException.html)
>
> **Consider change the character encoding of the JSON file**